# Negative GVIF values in multinomial logistic regression in R

Tags: r, multinomial-logit, variance-inflation-factor

I'm trying to check the vif for a multinomial logistic regression with categorical as well as continuous variables as explanatory variables.
I'm using the function vif() from car package in R.
However the values of the GVIF are coming very large and negative, it also gives a warning "No Intercept: vifs may not be sensible".

Please explain what is meant by a negative vif value here and also if there is any other way to check the VIF of a multinomial logistic regression.

Comment: Read the error message! Why did you fit a model without an intercept? It is often a bad idea. Then try to refit a model with an intercept, and recalculate vif. Or maybe you included an intercept in a way not recognized by the software as an intercept?

Comment: Hi @kjetic b halvorsen. Sorry I forgot to mention that the regression is run with an intercept term, still I am getting the error as mentioned in the question.
Also, the software is recognizing the intercept as it is giving out the coefficient as well as t stat and p values for the multinomial regression. I have used mlogit() to do the logistic regression.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I also get this error, while my model was fit with an intercept.